# TempDB not selectable for DBCC maintenance plan

Tags: sql-server, tempdb, dbcc, maintenance-plans, dbcc-checkdb

I'm trying to clean up some of our maintenance plans and noticed that our TempDB is not getting it's weekly dose of DBCC CHECKDB goodness.  I've tried to go into the maintenance plan and make sure it's there, but it's not showing up in the checkbox area.  Any ideas why that would happen or have any pointers to make tempDB selectable again? I know I can always just add an Execute SQL Task but I'd like to have this all taken care of in one step by the maintenance plan.  I've also tried creating a brand new plan and attempted to select it that way, still no joy.

It's a DW environment, 2008R2, 256GB RAM, 64 cores (HT enabled).  Our TempDB files/logs are on a FusionIO card by themselves so there's no contention.

Thanks again!

Comment: Why do you have to use a maintenance plan for this where you rely on picking databases from a GUI, instead of just building your own checkdb commands?

Comment: Also be aware that CheckDB against tempdb does not perform several checks (such as catalog and allocation), and tempdb is re-created from scratch on service restart. I would hope if there are underlying hardware problems that FusionIO would tell you about them long before DBCC will.

Comment: It's how this box was configured when I started.  I've since moved our primary production server over to a scripted approach and off maintenance plans , this one is next on the list, just wondering if anyone has seen this happen before and knew what was causing it?

Comment: I don't see tempdb either. Don't know how long it's been like that; I don't use maintenance plans on principle because they promote so many bad things. Maybe you can create one where you just select system databases (which is a separate option).

Comment: In official documentation for 2012/2014 its written that checkdb would not be there for tempdb in MP http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191002%28v=sql.110%29.aspx but I cannot see similar for 2008 R2. So yes as suggested you could write TSQL for it and schedule it accordingly

Comment: Well I'm using SSMS 2014 right now. We are upgrading to 2014 the beginning of next year so maybe it's SSMS that doesn't pick up tempdb in the options. Regardless, I'm moving this to a scripted approach but nice to know what was causing it. Thanks Aaron and Shanky, as always!

Comment: @AaronBertrand Interestingly per SQLSoldier corruption in tempdb may not be fixed after a service restart so it may be worth testing.  http://www.sqlsoldier.com/wp/sqlserver/day14of31daysofdisasterrecoveryfixingacorrupttempdb

Comment: @KennethFisher I didn't mean to imply it wasn't worth testing. Just wanted to be sure the OP was aware that it doesn't test as much as one might assume.

Comment: @AaronBertrand fair enough.  I had just recently read that post and thought it was interesting that tempdb isn't "reset" as much as I had thought.

Comment: @Kenneth I bet that's something that about 1% of the community knows. :-) Anyway, it's a fair point, I really didn't mean to downplay the checks or brush them aside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tempdb won't be available for you in the Mantainance Plan database list box, but you sure can run it as a script:

```
DBCC CHECKDB(N'tempdb')  WITH NO_INFOMSGS
```

According to Mr. Brent Ozar, you [SHOULD check tempdb](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/05/dbcc-checkdb-faq/) for integrity, and if Brent is saying that, that is good enough for me.

regards